# How to disable DNS resolution when using a HTTP proxy

Tags: network, dns, proxy

I'm running behind a corporate firewall and http proxy. The DNS resolves internal names but does not resolve external names. The proxy does allow connecting to external sites and when using this with Firefox everything is smooth. However, having this proxy configured in system preferences does not allow Safari or anything that uses the system preferences to browse the external sites.

A tcpdump shows that Safari tries to resolve the name of the site, fails doing so and then doesn't reach out to the proxy server. I tested a local setup and when DNS does resolve it will reach out to the proxy server.

This seems weird to me. If configured to use a proxy, it should just reach out to the proxy directly? What can I do to ensure this happens?

Comment: What does corporate IT say about this? They should be your first resource, and they may have an immediate answer for you.

Comment: They don't have an answer and would like to know it as well as it would reduce their support calls.

Comment: Which version of macOS? Does Google Chrome exhibit this problem?

Comment: Mojave. Chrome uses the system settings so yes it exposes the same issue.